# Access Values from HashMap without index values?

Tags: java, jsp

I have two values in my hashmap... How can i access those values without using for loops..

This is my hashmap code:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> obMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
obMap.put(new Integer(1),PartnerID);
obMap.put(new Integer(2),numwidgets);
return obMap;
```

I am returning values to java script method...how to read values in JSP if i get in obMap.

Comment: How do you want to access the values in the map? Do you use JSP?

Comment: @Sven- I am sorry, i mentioned java script, its JSP..i wrote java script function under JSP..Hope, this is clear

Comment: From code you've posted, I believe it's Java, but then you're talking about javascript. What language exactly do you need to do this operation in?

Comment: @gasan: I am calling java method from java script function...again i m retruning result to java script function...I want to print all values in java script function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> obMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
obMap.put(1,PartnerID);
obMap.put(2,numwidgets);
System.out.println(obMap.get(1));
System.out.println(obMap.get(2));
```

Note you don't need `new Integer(1)`. It's autoboxing.

Comment: Nice comment about auto(un)boxing, although I wouldn't consider explicitly boxing the scalars to be bad practice/style.

Comment: right...but this is java na...I want access values in java script

Comment: Then you are short on quite a lot of details. What system are you using to push the Java map into Javascript?

Comment: @Romain Actually, directly instantiating `Integer` is a bad idiom, the same as using `new String` as it prevents caching. And writing excess code is also not good practice.

Comment: @Vicky I can give you generic advice: you access a map entry in JavaScript with `map[key]`.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to call obMap.get(key) directly from java script

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in JSP, and you have objMap `HashMap` inside your jsp then you can simply access it using this scriplet in your javascript:

`<%=obMap.get(1)%>`

Answer (score 0):

From the JSP page you can access your `HashMap` through the following way:

```
<%=obMap.get(0)%> <!-- The first value in the map -->
<%=obMap.get(1)%> <!-- The second value in the map -->
```

Where this can be put in a JavaScript function or block in your JavaScript section of your JSP page.
Note that Java scriplets in a JSP page begin and end with <% and %> respectively.
when you want to include a value directly into a JavaScript variable <%= and %> are used to begin and end the value like above.

Hope this answer helps you.